# Filter DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I've searched the internet for a solution for my problem, me and my studygrp is making a datagridview that takes information from a classLibrary. All that works but now we got to filter it but all I can find is by bindingsource but that's not what I was thinking. I just want a simple filter so that you can enter something in a textbox and it shows it on the datagridview if it contains that information. I've tried:

```
((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = "FromColumn like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
```

But it doesn't work like I want it to hmmn... anyone that can help?

Answer (score 4):

Try BindingSource. It provides good extensive facilities of filtering

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
bs.Filter = "yourColumnName like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

Comment: thnx for the answer :D but i got System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
Message = objectReference has not been given to an instans of object

Comment: Thx again sami for ur answer :D now it half works better then before xD but the problem now is when i search it just give me a blank row? u know what that can be?

Comment: still adds a blank row, getting kinda frustrating ;/ im trying eveything but still no results

Comment: @Ra91 I just copy pasted it after testing in visual studio. Please share your earlier (than filtering) code. SO I be glad to solve your problem. However it is the correct answer just for filtering a databound gridview. I am not sure if you have really bound your datagridview correctly with a datatable. Please share it

Comment: Also works `BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)dataGridView1.DataSource;` `bs.Filter = ...`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DataView dv = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView;
dv.RowFilter = "FromColumn like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
```

Comment: what am i supposed to do with dataGridView1.DataBind();? it gives me that it doesnt contain a definition for dataBind?

Comment: We are programming in 3 tier architecture, Windows form for design, logic layer for processing information and datalayer for getting the data and saving it so the datagridview is bound by  dataGridView1.DataSource = logic.LoadMessages(); wich loads messages from the datalayer

Comment: System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  Message=not successful to convert an object of type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BegEntities.Email] to type System.Data.DataTable

Answer (score 2):

i've found this to suite my needs best:

the data you want to show in grid is stored in a BindingList ( supports INotifyPropertyCchanged  which is quite neat when you update the list ....)
so somwhere you define this BindingList:

```
public MyDataList = new BindingList<MyDataItem>();
```

assign it to the grid's datasource:

```
 myDataGrid.DataSource = MyDataList;
```

when "filter-button" is pressed, or what event you want do:

```
myDataGrid.DataSource = MyDataList.Where(ln => ln.propertyname.Contains(textBoxFilter.Text).ToList();
```

when resetting the filterm just set back orginal source

```
MyDataGrid.DataSource = MyDataList
```

hope it helps, greetings

Comment: I don't know what `ln` is in your code but your answer led me to another answer which had been eluding me for a while. So, thanks!

Comment: ln is just a placeholder/variable-name for linq expression ( method syntax )
you could use anything you want.. see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq