# FIlter DataGridView with datasource dictionary.values

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, filter, datatable

I'm familiar with row filtering in a dataTable, using DataView.

I would like to filter a datagridview, which has a datasource based on the values of a dictionary. So, not transformed to a datatable.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = _someDict.values.where(what you need).ToList();
```

For filtering I wanted to use something like this:
[Filter DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274792/filter-datagridview) (answer by Sami) or [Filtering DataGridView without changing datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource) (answers by Brad Bruce and Joe Sisk)

casting the datasource to dataTable like:

```
var dt = (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable);
```

returns null.

So I gave it a try by using a bindingSource.

```
_bindingSource.DataSource = _someDict.values.where(what you need).ToList();
dataGridView1.DataSource = _bindingSource;
```

DataGridView is populated with the correct data. But, when I try to filter like this:

```
_bindingSource.Filter= "MyColumn like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
```

the rows are not filtered and I can still see all rows. Even after
dataGridView1.DataSource = _bindingSource;
dataGridView1.Refresh();

Any suggestions? I know how to create a datatable from a list (I've got an extension for that), but I prefer to just bind the dictionary values to either a bindingSource or the dataGridView.
Kind regards,

Matthijs

Comment: DataView dv = (DataView)searchCustomersDataGridView.DataSource;

DataTable dt = dv.Table;

Use a dataview to get the datatable from a datagridview

Comment: With or without using a bindingSource, I get an exception that it cannot be casted to a dataView.

Comment: What does the exception say ?

Comment: In case of databinding:"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' to type 'System.Data.DataView'." When binding the list result directly to the datagridview:"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' to type 'System.Data.DataView'"

Comment: hummm...I guess I have to do the filtering via linq, unless someone has a bright idea on how to handle this. If you do, please let me know. Even if you read this post in the far future. I'm just curious how to handle this.